# How to fix Visual Studio 'Reference does not allow partially trusted callers' warnings in Error List

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a C# Console Application targeting .NET framework 4.5.2 (it runs as a Windows service)

I use NuGet packages.

The Visual Studio Error List shows many warnings of the pattern:

```
Reference '<nuget package>' does not allow partially trusted callers
```

It also has one interesting line that says:

```
Use of app.config binding redirects requires full trust
```

Interestingly enough, I also have a WPF Click-Once app in the same solution that uses many of the same packages, but it does not show the warnings.

I do not get compiler errors when building the console application.

Under the Properties > Security, I have checked "This is a full trust application".

I do not have access to the source code of the NuGet packages that are causing the warnings.  Many are very common packages like 'Ninject' and 'EntityFramework.SqlServer', etc.

The questions I have seen other SO questions like this one:

[Assembly does not allow partially trusted caller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487001/assembly-does-not-allow-partially-trusted-caller)

but it doesn't seem to fit my problem?

I've researched 'strong-named' assemblies, however the WPF Click-Once application that does not show the warnings does not use the Properties > Signing, and it also has bindingRedirect in its App.config?

Comment: `bindingRedirect` requires 'strong-named' assemblies. Perhaps this requirement is not satisfied.

Comment: Hi Dimitar, I have seen reference to this word.  I have researched, but don't know how/what to fix to make my assembly 'strong-named'?  The instructions from MS say use the properties 'Signing' to do this.  Interestingly, my Click-Once application does not have anything signed and it does not give the warnings?

Comment: Are you sure the foreign assemblies are 'strong-named' ?

Comment: I don't know?  I don't have access to the foreign assemblies.  They are from nuget.  They don't seem to be giving errors in the other WPF Click-Once application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487001/assembly-does-not-allow-partially-trusted-caller

Comment: This is not a duplicate, I linked the same question in my question.  That question is about how to allow partially trusted callers

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked settings in project properties => Security
[Project properties, security tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkWMN.png)

[image]

Comment: Best answer Vladimir. Thanks