# AngleSharp assembly must be fully trusted

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, anglesharp, trusted

I get this error when I try to call the constructor HtmlParser inside my webMethod in a aspx page

> Attempt by security transparent method
> 'AngleSharp.Browser.EncodingMetaHandler..ctor()' to access security
> critical method
> 'System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.EncodingProvider)'
> failed. Assembly 'AngleSharp, Version=0.14.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=e83494dcdc6d31ea' is partially trusted, which causes
> the CLR to make it entirely security transparent regardless of any
> transparency annotations in the assembly itself. In order to access
> security critical code, this assembly must be fully trusted.

When I run the webmethod on local IIS no problem,
when I run on server where my website is relaeased I get the error above.

Server is in share hosting ( Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard).
Trust Level is set to MEDIUM.

It's not possible to change server configuration.

What I've tried is:

- Sign all my generated libraries
- rebuild AngleSharp.dll adding attribute AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers  to the assembly

Can someone give me a suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assembly does not allow partially trusted caller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487001/assembly-does-not-allow-partially-trusted-caller)

Comment: There are multiple causes to this issue the underlying cause will depend on what technology your using, server deployment, etc. etc

Comment: Framework is 4.6.1

Comment: Server is  Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
Being a shared server, I have no possibility to apply any configuration change.

Comment: I add some other details. The Web Site runs on a shared hosting (ARUBA) where the trust level is set to "medium".
In additon I got the same error with Paypal SDK. 
I suppose that the only solution is to request to my host to move from MEDIUM to FULL